# I cannot get file import to work in my python flask app

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, aws-cloud9

I am using AWS cloud9 IDE and Python flask to develop a webpage where users can create an account and sign in. However when I run my program I get  from flasklab8 import app
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/flasklab8/flasklab8/app/**init**.py", line 15, in 
    from flasklab8 import routes
ImportError: cannot import name 'routes'. There are a few other files for this web page but I think this is the only file that is causing the issue if needed I can edit in the rest of the code. I also do not know if this is because I am using AWS. The code for the problem file is below:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '5791628bb0b13ce0c676dfde280ba245'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'

from flasklab8 import routes
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your file chain is

```
/home/ec2-user/environment/flasklab8/flasklab8/app/init.py
```

Unless you are doing something really strange, you routes.py file should be in your app folder, not your flasklab8, meaning your import statement is incorrect. It should read

```
from app import routes
```

Comment: So I tried to change that and it now errors with File "/home/ec2-user/environment/flasklab8/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flasklab8 import app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flasklab8'

Comment: Flask is very specific about where directories need to be and also where certain lines of code need to be. I'm assuming you are following a tutorial or making the best of their documentation.

I recommend you check this tutorial out https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

This is the best flask tutorial on the web and works flawlessly. Double check each step to figure out where you went wrong.